# i want to reshape this table using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have this table as a csv file.

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | y | 55 |
|  | z | 12 |
| 99 | y | 26 |
| 25 | y | 14 |
|  | z | 88 |

And I expect this:

| col1 | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 55 | 12 |
| 99 | 26 | nan |
| 25 | 14 | 88 |

I tried df.stack() but it didn't work

Comment: This should do it: `df.pivot(columns='col2', values='col3', index='col1').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: richardec, I tried what you suggested but it didn't work. I got this message error:    ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape